# Projectfork uninstall issue

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

When I uninstalled (or disabled only) a  [projectfork](http://www.projectfork.net/)
 component for joomla 2.5 I got the 404. error. What should I do for properly and complete uninstalling this component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To properly uninstall any extension, it's the same process.

1. Go to the admin Panel
2. Go to Extension Manager
3. Click on the "Manage" button
4. Select the extension and click "Uninstall"

If the extension has been developed properly, it should delete all references from the database as well as the files from the folders. If it doesn't, you will just have to manually delete the files that are still there and delete the SQL tables and a row from `#__extensions`